# C# - Associate checkList buttons with methods

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I created an appliaction which deletes files from different directories.
I have made a different method for each directory.

In the UI I want the user to pick which directories he wants to erase.

Picking is done with a checkbox list and eventually when the user picks all directories he wants empty he can hit the play button.

My question is: what is the right approach here?
Is it possible to associate the check buttons with methods?
Or should I make a long branching code behind the play button?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Windows Forms application on visual studio

Comment: check the [ItemCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) event of checklist.

Comment: For me, the key question is: why have you "made a different method for each directory"?  Does something prohibit you from generalizing your "delete files" functionality into some kind of function, even if that function takes some kind of parameters?

Comment: The methods are different. Each method receives a computer name or an array of all users from the user directory. each method has a diffrent path only their base which is the pc name is common to all. in some methods you cant just delete the files there are checks to be made

Comment: I don't have time to formalize this as an answer (anyone else is welcome to), but you will want to look into [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) as a way to get a variable that holds a function, and [Control.Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) as a part of every winforms Control that holds an object associated with that control.  With the two of them, you can make clicking on the play button just loop through all checked items and call the `Func` within the `Tag`.

Comment: by checkbox list you mean `CheckedListBox` control. Do you? or there are number of `CheckBox` controls for each choice of directory to be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this kind of thing:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Action> _selectedActions = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Apple");
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Banana");
        this.checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Cherry");

        _selectedActions = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
        {
            { "Apple", Apple },
            { "Banana", Banana },
            { "Cherry", Cherry },
        };
    }

    private void Apple() { MessageBox.Show("Ran Apple"); }
    private void Banana() { MessageBox.Show("Ran Banana"); }
    private void Cherry() { MessageBox.Show("Ran Cherry"); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var action in this.checkedListBox1
            .CheckedItems
            .Cast<string>()
            .Select(x => _selectedActions[x]))
        {
            action();
        }
    }
```

The important part with this approach is the section of code that sets the checkbox items also sets up the `Dictionary<string, Action>` and this helps prevent having a name mismatch with the checkbox items and the dictionary keys. In all other ways this code is strongly-typed.

Comment: It looks better than my idea, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

If the name of the folder in your CheckedListBox? matches that of the method to run, then you can use Reflection.  For example, I have "cat", "dog", and "fish" listed, and can run the corresponding method (when checked) like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string folder in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(folder, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (mi != null)
            {
                mi.Invoke(this, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void cat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("cat");
    }

    private void dog()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dog");
    }

    private void fish()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("fish");
    }
```